# In Backbone, any difference between model.get('foo') and model.attributes.foo?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone.js, there are two ways you can get the value of a single attribute:

1. `var foo = model.get('foo');`
2. `var foo = model.attributes.foo;`

The `.get()` approach is the one recommended in the docs, but presumably it's a bit slower, as it involves an extra function call.

Are there any reasons why I shouldn't use the `.attributes` approach? Are there any cases where it would cause unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of encapsulation. By using a get method you are saying I don't care how it's implemented I just want that attribute. So in future if you want to override your get method to return something more meaningful, you would not have make a code change everywhere you are using that attribute.

For e.g., If your model has an attribute cost associated with it which is a number.

```
model.get('cost') //would give you that number say 1999.99
```

Now in future suppose you want it to return a formatted string, you can override the get method.

```
model.get('cost') // same method would now give you $1999.99 or EUR 1999,99 in french :)
```

Also you are reducing the amount of code and increasing the readability.

model.get('foo') reads much better than model.attributes.foo; and it's shorter as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, in your question, the `.get()` approach is the one recommended in the docs.  Although calling the attribute directly is going to save you a few nano seconds, you should not do it.

The reason is because it may encourage someone reading your code to use that same method to set an attribute: `model.attributes.foo = 'blah';`

I probably don't have to tell you that this would be bad.  The code may appear to work because you're getting the correct value on the model, but you are bypassing all the change tracking logic built in to backbone.  No events will be triggered if you set an attribute that way.

That being said - if no one else is reading your code or changing your code but you, and you care about those extra nanoseconds *that* much, and you know that you will ***never*** make that type of a mistake in the future.  Then by all means, use the attributes property directly.